# NullPointerException while nothing is null

Tags: java, android, debugging, exception, nullpointerexception

Ok, this is very frustrating.

My code is following:

```
accept.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_navigator_accept_checked);
ViewPager vp = (ViewPager)activity.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = (ViewPagerAdapter)vp.getAdapter();

MyAdapter ma = (MyAdapter)(adapter.finalExamTypeList.getAdapter());

int selected = ma.getSelectedItem();
selected -= adapter.finalExamTypeList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

I'm getting `NullPointerException` in this line:

```
MyAdapter ma = (MyAdapter)(adapter.finalExamTypeList.getAdapter());
```

Seems like pretty easy to find out - either `adapter` or `adapter.finalExamTypeList` should be `null`.

But when I checked it in debug mode, nothing in this line is really `null`. Everything is initialized and it's initialized properly. Also this `adapter.finalExamTypeList.getAdapter()` returns properly `MyAdapter` object.

So I was a bit worried, but anyway, I tried to make those conditions here:

```
accept.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_navigator_accept_checked);
ViewPager vp = (ViewPager)activity.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = (ViewPagerAdapter)vp.getAdapter();

if(adapter != null) {
    if(adapter.finalExamTypeList != null) {
        if(adapter.finalExamTypeList.getAdapter() != null) {
            MyAdapter ma = (MyAdapter)(adapter.finalExamTypeList.getAdapter());

            int selected = ma.getSelectedItem();
            selected -= adapter.finalExamTypeList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        }
    }
}
```

But still, `NullPointerException` in the same place.

Log:

```
06-23 09:25:28.260: W/dalvikvm(1967): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception raised
06-23 09:25:28.260: W/dalvikvm(1967):              in Landroid/os/Process;.setArgV0 (Ljava/lang/String;)V (GetStringCritical)
06-23 09:25:28.260: W/dalvikvm(1967): Pending exception is:
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967): Ljava/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException;:
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967): Caused by:
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967): Ljava/lang/NullPointerException;:
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at pl.lodz.uni.myproject.CircleNavigator$1.onClick(CircleNavigator.java:99)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967): "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb5f1bc38 self=0x9240e48
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   | sysTid=1967 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-2145907712
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at android.os.Process.setArgV0(Native Method)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3668)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-23 09:25:28.260: I/dalvikvm(1967):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 09:25:28.260: E/dalvikvm(1967): VM aborting
```

Anyone has any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Can you post the logcat as well?

Comment: @Plato Sorry, I just added it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Not that many, it's ok. :-)

Comment: @Mosquito post CircleNavigator$1.onClick

Comment: @blackbelt This is what I just posted, this code. There's nothing else.

Comment: what`s really bother me is the JNI warning. Are you working with the ndk?

Comment: @blackbelt No, the funny thing is that I don't even have ndk on my computer.

Comment: What is pl.lodz.uni.myproject.CircleNavigator$1.onClick(CircleNavigator.java:99)?

Comment: @Elist The line that I posted. `MyAdapter ma = (MyAdapter)(adapter.finalExamTypeList.getAdapter());`

Comment: What if you delete the cast and just do `adapter.finalExamTypeList.getAdapter();`?

Comment: Tried that too, still the same. :-(

Comment: Did you write the `adapter.finalExamTypeList.getAdapter()` method yourself? If so, can you show it?

Comment: @MichaelButscher No, `finalExamTypeList` is normal `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. It appears it was some kind of a bug or something. After I restarted eclipse a few times, it told me to update my ADT, so I did and it solved this problem, no `NullPointerException`. Magic.

Answer (score 4):

> But when I checked it in debug mode, nothing in this line is really null.

There are a couple of possibilities you haven't considered.

- It could be a race condition that you don't observe in the debugger because it doesn't occur when you single-step the code.
- There could be a bug in the debugger.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't really understand the first possibility. 

And according to second possibility - that's why I made those conditions where I check if those things are `null`, but that line is still being called, so it means they're not `null` I assume.

Comment: @Mosquito First possiblity can happen if you use multiple threads and another modifies the data during the check runs. But this is unlikely to happen everytime

Comment: @MichaelButscher - Actually, it *could* be a race condition where the *normal* behaviour is that fails ... and it only succeeds if you slow one of the threads to a crawl by single-stepping.  But this is all hypothetical ...

Answer (score 0):

[ViewPager.getAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getAdapter%28%29) only returns the adapter. Unless you're initializing it somewhere else, you should create a new `ViewPagerAdapter`. Also, you don't seem to call [ViewPager.setAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setAdapter%28android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter%29) either, which is necessary before calling `getAdapter` anyway.

Comment: I don't get it. "Only returns the adapter"? Yes, that's what I want it to do, to return the adapter. And everything is initialized as I said in my question. `ViewPager.setAdapter` is called much earlier.

Comment: In one of you comments you said "...There's nothing else" referring to the code you posted. I thought that you didn't call `setAdapter` and therefore calling `getAdapter` wouldn't initialize your `ViewPagerAdapter` object.

Comment: Nah, I said it about this `onClick` method which blackbelt wanted me to post - there's nothing else in this method, but project itself is much bigger. Anyway, adapter is set earlier.